# NoSQL Modeling fields visibility for certain users

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql, firebase-security

I'm new to NoSQL modeling and I am currently confronted with a problem of which I do not know how to solve it.

Say I have a calendar and some people are allowed to see certain events. These people are categorised into 3 groups. In SQL, I would've given each event an integer and I would've made a bit-wise comparator. In NoSQL (Firestore in this case), I need to specify certain rules but, somehow I can't forbid someone to view a certain entry in a document. I have an idea on how to solve this, but it seems very... ineffective. Namely, make a collection where all the events are stored (only accessible by the admin) and based on the entries, update 3 documents in which the events are stored as well.

Is there a better method? I'm a bit new to this but it feels very bad.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean by *I need to specify certain rules but, somehow I can't forbid someone to view a certain entry in a document.*? What certain rules? Do you want only need to read a specific field from a document?

Answer (score 0):

Reads in Cloud Firestore are performed at the document level, meaning you either retrieve the full document, or you retrieve nothing. There is no way to retrieve a partial document. You cannot rely solely on the security rules to prevent users from reading a specific field.

If you want certain fields to be hidden from some users, then you have to put them in a separate document. You might consider creating a document in a private subcollection. And then write security rules that have different levels of access for the two collections.

You can refer [Control Access to Specific Field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields) for more information and example.

Comment: Hey @Albert, did this answer help you?